# Can I get multiple domains running on one windows 2016 server?

Tags: windows, iis

I've got a VPS, it's now running Windows 2016 and I've installed IIS, I managed to get my domain pointed to my IP and run a simple asp.net core website successfully live. Great!

Now I'm not sure if I could add another domain to hit this server?
In IIS I'm having to publish my asp.net core files to the "Default Web Site" folder `~/inetpub/wwwroot` - so if anything pointing to my server IP always hits that folder only, (how) can I set up another site?

Please bear with me, I'm a meddling software dev, but networking and infrastructure is very new to me.

---

**edit** I imagine this is definitely possible and something to do with nameservers, but the VPS provider kinda sorted my newly registered domain pointing to my IP so maybe I could just ask them - although any advice or links is much appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to host multiple websites on differents domains on the same webserver.

Create a new site in IIS and fill the "Host name" field.
If you want to change this value afterwards, select your website, click on "Bindings...", write the desired host name in "Host name".

[image: IIS Bindings - Host name]

IIS will be able to "distinguish" which website should be served with the hostname.

In fact, when the browser accesses the website, it tells the webserver the wanted hostname with the "Host" HTTP Header, or ":authority" if HTTP/2 is used:

[image: HTTP 1 Host] [image: HTTP2 authority]

Comment: Cool, so even though I don't have another domain to test on now, I should be able to take stuff out of the default folder and setup my current domain on another IIS created site. I'll give that a try!

Comment: It should be noted, that when using this technique, specifying an IP will not work.  You have to leave the IP on "All Unassigned".

Answer (score 2):

> Now I'm not sure if I could add another domain to hit this server?

Yes, you can.

You need to add host headers in the bindings for each website. The host headers should match the FQDN of each website (www.domainA.com, www.domainB.com, etc.). IIS will then direct incoming clients to the corresponding website.